# CakePHP ACL gives error

Tags: cakephp, acl

I've set this in my AppController.php

```
    $this->Auth->authorize = array(
    'Actions' => array(
        'actionPath' => 'controllers/'
    )
);
```

This is in my Aco table:

```
id  parent_id   model   foreign_key     alias   lft     rght
25  NULL             NULL   NULL    controllers     1   2
```

This is my Aro table:

```
id  parent_id   model   foreign_key     alias   lft     rght
1   1           Group   1               NULL      27    30
15  14          User    1               NULL      28    29
```

This is my Aco_Aro table:

```
id  aro_id  aco_id  _create     _read   _update     _delete
15    1       25      1             1     1            1
```

And i get this error:

```
    Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => Test
            [group_id] => 1
            [created] => 2012-03-24 22:47:33
            [modified] => 2012-03-24 22:47:33
        )

)

Aco: controllers/Posts/index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user **Test** belongs the Aro **14** as seen in your Aro table. The parent_id field in the table Aro defines the tree.

```
// For eg. If i have two groups Administrator, User
Groups
id | name
11 | Administrator
22 | User
```

And
    Users
    // I have users table as

```
id | name | group_id
 7 |  KK  |    11
 9 |  SS  |    22
```

My Aro table would be

```
ARO
id | parent_id | alias | foreign_key  
 1 |   null    |  adm  |   11            // Group
 2 |   null    |  usr  |   22            // Group
 3 |    1      |  kk   |   7            // User
 4 |    2      |  SS   |   9            // User
```

From your Aro/Acl setup, cake's ACL component is not able to find **14**. 
If you want to make your life easier you can try [Acl Plugin](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl). This really simplifies some obvious tasks.