# Just how strong exactly is CakePHP's ACL Component?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

I have read numerous times here and on various websites that the ACL Component is a very powerful tool.  Yet the next sentence usually begins with a version of "However, the cake manual poorly documents this and so this is the system that I am using instead."  I am a programming novice and have definitely struggled with learning Cake because of the docs as well; I am at a loss as to what exactly makes the AclComponent so strong, since everyone recommends it but many are still using something else.  Can anyone suggest specific examples or tutorials that will help me understand this component better?  For example, what kinds of code it helps me avoid having to write, how to limit access by each user instead of the entire group, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake's ACL system is powerful because it's extremely flexible and allows very fine grained control over the access to your application. Most people use it in a basic sort of way, i.e., this user/group has access to this controller method. While this is the common use case, you can also use it to say, limit a model's access to another model's `create` action.

For example, to limit an Admin group to only creating records for a PrivateModel model:

```
// add aco
$this->Acl->Aco->add(array(
'alias' => 'PrivateModel'
'model' => 'PrivateModel',
'foreign_key' => null
));

// add aro
$this->Acl->Aro->array(array(
'alias' => 'Admin'
'model' => 'Group',
'foreign_key' => 1
));

// allow Admin to read PrivateModel #1
$this->Acl->allow('Admin', 'PrivateModel1', 'create');

// check permission
$allowed = $this->Acl->check('Admin', 'PrivateModel', 'read'); // true
$allowed = $this->Acl->check('Admin', 'PrivateModel', 'create'); // false
```

The default answer to "should I use ACL" is often "no" simply because it can take some time to set up and understand. Cake's ACL examples were enough to get me going on it when I originally had no understanding of even the ACL concepts or MPTT trees.

Currently I have an app that has groups as AROs, and the ACLComponent uses the controller to check an `isAuthorized()` method which pulls the group from the logged in user and uses it to check see if the action is authorized. Again, this is probably the most basic approach to ACL.

Comment: Limiting a model's access, now, see THAT is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Watered down, ACL is just "can such-and-such access so-and-so." What those are is essentially up to you :)

Comment: Well, this part I do understand.  I was hoping that I could see more than just very basic examples of usage from a few SO users.  What you said about limiting a model's access, see I never would have thought about that...I'm looking for stuff like that I guess.

Comment: I added a little example about models accessing other models, hope it makes sense. It's not complete, because it doesn't talk about your `isAuthorized` function or setting up the AuthComponent to automatically check authorization, but hopefully points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, that does clarify it a bit more for me, tho you lost me at $this->Acl->allow('Admin', 'PrivateModel1', 'create');  The add aco/ add aro arrays you established, Acl recognizes the difference between models/groups/actions when you call the allow() method? I guess that is kinda cool and powerful after all....

Comment: Those were references to the alias, which it then can use to pull the ids from. You can use an array syntax instead of aliases, as stated in the book. Like `$this->Acl->allow(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 1), 'PrivateModel1', 'create');`

Comment: What I don't understand is that for the DbAcl, `$this->Acl->allow()` will not create an acos_aros record. If the record doesn't already exist it fails. So how do you create the acos_aros records?

Comment: @geoidesic it should actually create the records. It's possible that one of the ACO/ARO nodes are missing which causes the save to fail (check logs).

Answer (score 1):

As you have already pointed out in your question "However ... cake documentation", **I couldn't agree more.**

I have seen many of my team members in past struggle to grab the concept of whole Acl, Aro and Aco, and cake's documentation may be adds additional complexity to it than solving it.

The real magic of ACL begins with **Aro** and **Aco**.

```
ARO (Access Request Object) - They are the entities who request for services. 
for eg. Users, Roles (Admin, Manager, Moderator)

ACO (Access Control Object) - They are the entities which are requested. 
for eg. Posts, Posts->add, Posts->view, Posts->edit
```

We can configure our models with [requester](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1547/Acts-As-a-Requester) behavior such that everytime new record is created, it gets automatically synced with corresponding Aro.

As already demonstrated by jeremyharris, you can use Aro and Aco mapping with corresponding privilages to limit/control the access control of your application.

Also, you can make your life pretty easy with ACL by using a plugin [Alaxos ACL](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl) This plugin really simplifies the whole ACL setup, especially from UI perspective

The cake console also provides a shell to initialize your db for ACL setup

```
cake acl initdb    // cakephp 1.1, from shell with create db setup for acl
$ cake schema create DbAcl    // cakephp 1.2 and above
```

There is an additional plugin from Markstory called [AclExtras](https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras), it provides you a shell to make acl management more easy like creating aco nodes, testing and recovering aco, aro trees. It's an amazing plugin.

Comment: I think for at least myself the concept of Aro and Aco is easy to understand, it's all the everything else where I get tripped up, like acts as a requester and parentNode(), like you suggested.  Definitely +1 for the plugin links, thank you!

Comment: Acts as requester creates corresponding Aro node.

It is very hard to define permission per user, hence we assign them to groups and then define permission for the group they belong to. For eg. Admin, Managers, Moderators. So in order to tell which group the user belongs we use parentNode(), basically what it does is define the parent_id (role which user belongs to). I think my other answer on this subject may shed some more light to it. :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859088/cakephp-acl-gives-error/9859156#9859156